# Numerical integration of a numpy array in incremental time steps

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I have two arrays. The first one is time in terms of Age (yrs) and the second one is a parameter that needs to be integrated with respect to time.

```py
age = [5.00000e+08, 5.60322e+08, 6.27922e+08, 7.03678e+08, 7.88572e+08,
       8.83709e+08, 9.90324e+08, 1.10980e+09, 1.24369e+09, 1.39374e+09,
       1.56188e+09, 1.75032e+09, 1.96148e+09, 2.19813e+09, 2.46332e+09,
       2.76050e+09, 3.09354e+09, 3.46676e+09, 3.88501e+09, 4.35371e+09,
       4.87897e+09, 5.46759e+09, 6.12722e+09, 6.86644e+09, 7.69484e+09,
       8.62318e+09, 9.66352e+09, 1.08294e+10, 1.21359e+10, 1.36000e+10]
sfr = [1.86120543e-02, 1.46680445e-02, 1.07275184e-02, 8.56960274e-03,
       6.44041855e-03, 4.93194263e-03, 3.69203448e-05, 2.69813985e-04,
       6.17644783e-04, 1.00780427e-02, 1.20645391e-02, 3.05009362e-02,
       3.91535011e-02, 5.35479858e-02, 7.36489068e-02, 9.63931263e-02,
       1.11108326e-01, 1.47781221e-01, 1.63057763e-01, 2.27429626e-01,
       2.20941333e-01, 2.74413180e-01, 2.72010867e-01, 4.32215233e-01,
       5.79654549e-01, 7.39362218e-01, 9.41168727e-01, 1.18868347e+00,
       1.42839043e+00, 1.91326333e+00]
```

I want to perform integration of sfr array with respect to age array, but in steps.
For example, the first integration should contain only the first elements of both arrays, the second integration should contain the first 2 elements of both arrays, the third should have first 3 elements of both arrays and so on and so forth. And save the integration result for each step in a single output array.

Answer (score 0):

The exact form of your desired result is not so clear. So, here are 2 posibilities:

```
age = [5.00000e+08, 5.60322e+08, 6.27922e+08, 7.03678e+08, 7.88572e+08,
       8.83709e+08, 9.90324e+08, 1.10980e+09, 1.24369e+09, 1.39374e+09,
       1.56188e+09, 1.75032e+09, 1.96148e+09, 2.19813e+09, 2.46332e+09,
       2.76050e+09, 3.09354e+09, 3.46676e+09, 3.88501e+09, 4.35371e+09,
       4.87897e+09, 5.46759e+09, 6.12722e+09, 6.86644e+09, 7.69484e+09,
       8.62318e+09, 9.66352e+09, 1.08294e+10, 1.21359e+10, 1.36000e+10]
sfr = [1.86120543e-02, 1.46680445e-02, 1.07275184e-02, 8.56960274e-03,
       6.44041855e-03, 4.93194263e-03, 3.69203448e-05, 2.69813985e-04,
       6.17644783e-04, 1.00780427e-02, 1.20645391e-02, 3.05009362e-02,
       3.91535011e-02, 5.35479858e-02, 7.36489068e-02, 9.63931263e-02,
       1.11108326e-01, 1.47781221e-01, 1.63057763e-01, 2.27429626e-01,
       2.20941333e-01, 2.74413180e-01, 2.72010867e-01, 4.32215233e-01,
       5.79654549e-01, 7.39362218e-01, 9.41168727e-01, 1.18868347e+00,
       1.42839043e+00, 1.91326333e+00]

integr_pairs = [[(a, s) for a, s in zip(age[:i], sfr[:i])] for i in range(1, len(age))]
print(integr_pairs)
    # [[(500000000.0, 0.0186120543)], [(500000000.0, 0.0186120543), (560322000.0, 0.0146680445)], ....

integr_list = [[item for t in [(a, s) for a, s in zip(age[:i], sfr[:i])] for item in t ]for i in range(1, len(age))]
print(integr_list)
    # [[500000000.0, 0.0186120543], [500000000.0, 0.0186120543, 560322000.0, 0.0146680445],
```